# Trouble Writing Tests with printf in C

Tags: c, printing, valgrind

Let me start off by saying that this question is much longer than I anticipated it to be. It only appears that way because I have to include my code, Makefile, and Valgrind output. I broke up this question into headers that you can find below. I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't seem to figure out what might be causing the issue.

### Expected, Receiving

Using hardcoded values from the `construct_buf` function given in the `MRE` section below, the first two tests should fail and I should receive this output:

```
[ Test Failed ]
  Expected: ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
  Got     : cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
[ Test Failed ]
  Expected: 248d6a61d20638b8e5c026930c3e6039a33ce45964ff2167f6ecedd419db06c1
  Got     : cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
[ Test Passed ]
```

But the last one, for some reason, comes out like this:

```
[ Test Failed ]
  Expected: ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
  Got     : cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
[ Test Failed ]
  Expected: 248d6a61d20638b8e5c026930c3e6039a33ce45964ff2167f6ecedd419db06c1
  Got     : cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
[ Test Failed ]
  Expected: 414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
  Got     : cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
```

What even is `414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad`?

### Code

My main function is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sha256.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char* outputs[] = {
        "ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad",
        "248d6a61d20638b8e5c026930c3e6039a33ce45964ff2167f6ecedd419db06c1",
        "cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1",
    };

    char* vectors[] = {
        "abc",
        "abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq",
        "abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmnoijklmnopjklmnopqklmnopqrlmnopqrsmnopqrstnopqrstu",
    };
    
    sha256_ctx* ctx = malloc(sizeof *ctx);
    char buf[65]; // 64 chars for hash, 1 char for null termination
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        init_sha256(ctx);
        construct_buf(ctx, buf); // convert ctx into hash that is stored in buf
        if (memcmp(outputs[i], buf, 64))
        {
            printf("[ Test Failed ]\n  Expected: %s\n  Got     : %s\n", outputs[i], buf);
        }
        else {
            printf("[ Test Passed ]\n");
        }
    }
    free(ctx);
}
```

It should be worth noting that `init_sha256` just looks like this (pretty much just resets the values):

```
void init_sha256(sha256_ctx* ctx)
{
    ctx->datalen = 0;
    ctx->bitlen = 0;
    ctx->state[0] = 0x6a09e667;
    ctx->state[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
    ctx->state[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
    ctx->state[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
    ctx->state[4] = 0x510e527f;
    ctx->state[5] = 0x9b05688c;
    ctx->state[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
    ctx->state[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
}
```

Where `sha256_ctx` looks like so:

```
typedef uint8_t byte_t;
typedef uint32_t word_t;

typedef struct SHA256_CTX_STRUCT
{
    byte_t data[64];
    uint8_t datalen;
    uint64_t bitlen;
    word_t state[8];
} sha256_ctx;
```

### MRE

For a minimum reproducible example, the `construct_buf` function builds the hash from some hardcoded integer values. It looks like this:

```
void construct_buf(sha256_ctx* ctx, char* buf)
{
    ctx->state[0] = 3478853287;
    ctx->state[1] = 2024768384;
    ctx->state[2] = 57468318;
    ctx->state[3] = 2063897143;
    ctx->state[4] = 186948369;
    ctx->state[5] = 3908074065;
    ctx->state[6] = 2947302659;
    ctx->state[7] = 2063526353;
    // convert words into their hexadecimal representation
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        buf += sprintf(buf, "%08x", ctx->state[i]);
    }
    buf[64] = '\0';
}
```

When converted to their hex values, these integers should produce the hash:

```
cf5b16a778af8380036ce59e7b0492370b249b11e8f07a51afac45037afee9d1
```

### Compiling

(Version: `Homebrew clang version 12.0.1`)
My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

EXEC = out
SRCS = $(shell find src -type f -name '*.c')
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

### Valgrind

(Version: `valgrind-3.18.0.GIT-lbmacos`)
I'm assuming I have some kind of memory mismanagement in my program somewhere(?). Valgrind gives me some warnings about large allocations even though I'm not making any:

```
==36137== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2009c000, 0x80001fe9c000) (defined)
==36137== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2009c000, 0x7fff7fd64000) (defined)
==36137== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff8e2f0000, 0x7fffc009c000) (noaccess)
==36137== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffc009c000, 0x7fffe2ebc000) (defined)
==36137== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffe2ebc000, 0x7fffffe00000) (noaccess)
```

And an uninitialized value error that points to `main.c:57`, which is the line that prints that the test failed:

```
==36137== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==36137==    at 0x7FFF203ED91A: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x7FFF202BB194: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x7FFF202C3E3B: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x7FFF202E8974: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x7FFF202C0FF5: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x7FFF202BF165: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==36137==    by 0x10000339F: main (main.c:57)
==36137==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==36137==    at 0x100011025: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
```

Valgrind reports no memory leaks and `3 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`.

Interestingly enough, if I test each one individually outside of a loop, like so:

```
sha256_ctx* ctx = malloc(sizeof *ctx);
char* vec0 = "abc";
char* exp0 = "ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad";
char buf[65];
init_sha256(ctx);
update_sha256(ctx, vec0, strlen(vec0), buf);
printf("%d - %s\n", memcmp(buf, exp0, 64), buf);

// etc... 2 other tests identical to the one above
```

It works as expected. Any ideas? As always, I appreciate the help!

### Edit

Changed loop to (in `construct_buf`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    snprintf(buf + (i*8), 65-(i*8), "%08x", ctx->state[i]);
}
data[64] = '\0';
```

Comment: Take some time to think a little more about `buf += sprint(...)` followed by `buf[64] = '\0'`... Try to explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) where you set the terminator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I couldn't, LOL. Thanks for suggesting that - I definitely won't forget that strategy. I updated the question with an edit of the new statement. If I were to explain to my rubber duck now: *Essentially, what I'm doing is appending 8 characters to the buf variable on each iteration of the loop. Eight iterations of appending 8 characters totals 64 characters. I need to set the null terminator explicitly at the 65th character (64th index) after the loop.*

Comment: You can still do the `buf += ...` but then you have to remember that after the loop `buf` is already pointing to the 65:th element of the array, and you can do just `*buf = '\0'`.

Comment: gmdev  `sprintf(buf, "%08x", ctx->state[i]);` is a little fishy.  I'd expect `.state` to be a fixed width type to support sha256.  `"%x"` expects an `unsigned` and if `unsigned` is not 32-bit, like 16, code will fail.

Comment: How does `sha256_ctx` look like? Are the fields pointers or arrays?

Comment: @gmdev Debug tip: `printf("[ Test Failed ]\n  Expected: %s\n  Got     : %s\n", outputs[i], buf);` is attempting to print after a _failure_.  Do not assume `buf` contains a _string_.  Use a limit and sentinels .   `printf("Got     : <%.64s>\n", buf);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, I see. Simple fix, then. So I was essentially overwriting memory at whatever position `buf[64]` is which somehow affected where the test strings were stored?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `state` is an 8 element array of `uint32_t`.  Regarding your second comment, I like that approach - I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Gerhardh see the end of the `Code` section, I just added it.

Comment: gmdev, for max portability use  `"%08" PRIx32` with `uint32_t`, not `"%08x'`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [and you can do just *buf = '\0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287552/trouble-writing-tests-with-printf-in-c?noredirect=1#comment122464011_69287552) --> Not needed as `*buf` is 0 already at that point.  Each prior `sprintf()` writes 9 bytes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica shouldn't it only write 8 bytes? Or is there a null character appended on each call?

Comment: gmdev, `sprintf(buf, "ABC");` writes 4 bytes to `buf[]`: `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'\0'`, not 3.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I see, so if I were using `sprintf`, the result would be something like `cf5b16a7\078af8380\0...`?

Comment: gmdev, No.  `sprintf()` returns the number printed, _not_ counting the _null character_.  You will get `01234567\0` then printing 8 bytes later, the original `buf[]` is `0123456789ABCDEF\0`, ...  `buf += ...` code writes 9 bytes the first time, 9 bytes the 2nd time - starting with overwriting the prior null character - forming a string of 16 bytes + null character (17 written in all)

Comment: Which version of macOs is this on?

Comment: The `set address range perms` messages are probably related to the Valgrind host creating the runtime stack for the guest. It's safe to ignore these messages.